# Default compression for InflaterInputStream/DeflaterOutputStream

Tags: java, compression, inputstream, default, outputstream

According to the javadoc for [InflaterInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html), for its single-arg constructor (with just an InputStream), the input stream is initialized with `a default decompressor and buffer size`. The question is, what exactly is the default decompressor and buffer size? Same thing for the [DeflaterOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 2):

The inflator is just a

```
new java.util.zip.Inflator()
```

and buffer size is 512 bytes.

You can see this by navigating into the source for the InflaterInputStream constructor.  Don't have the JDK source attached in your IDE?  Stop everything and set that up, it is essential.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.java.html), you see it simply creates an instance of `java.util.zip.Inflater`:

```
public InflaterInputStream(InputStream in) {
    this(in, new Inflater());
    usesDefaultInflater = true;
}
```

The only difference in handling is that on closing the `InflaterInputStream` the 'default' `Inflater` gets closed (using [`end()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html#end%28%29)), which doesn't happen if an instance of `Inflater` is passed to one of the other constructors.

Presumably passing your own allows you to use a different implementation, or reuse it etc.